# Is there any way to add non-element-contained text to a $("")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a JavaScript framework to build HTML documents. First a virtual document is built using jQuery. Right now, I'm experimenting with jQuery's "add" function like so:

```
$(target).append($("").add($("<div>")).add($("<span>")))
```

> *The framework concatenates these calls to build the virtual document before it is appended to the target - this simplified code sample isn't literally what I'm doing. The reason for adding the first $("") is because the framework starts by creating an empty jQuery selection then adds stuff to it. Sub-documents are recursively created and added to parent elements.*

This works fine for concatenating elements together, but what if I want to concatenate text? Let's say I want to have something like this rendered:

```
<div></div> Outside the box!
```

I can't just do `$("<div>").add("Outside the box!")` Also, `$.after()` doesn't seem to work unless the `<div>` is already on the DOM.

Is this functionality supported by jQuery? If not, are there any workarounds?

Comment: @Amadan Unfortunately the supposed duplicate is for a completely different issue. Also, the text being concatenated to the div will be from the framework's future users, and may contain markup that I don't want to escape. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use simple string concatenation with current HTML of element: `$('<div>').html($('<div>').html() + 'Outside the box!')`

---

Since your code DOM is *in memory* and not actual HTML, you need to use multi-line code:

```
var $div = $('<div>', {html: $('<div>')});
$div.html($div.html() + "Outside the box!");
```

Comment: Ok this works. Basically, create a temporary parent div to contain the so-called virtual sub-documents. Since I don't want to keep the outer div, how do I copy all the stuff out of it and into it's final destination, once that destination is known? When I do `$div.children()`, it doesn't select the text after the inner div.

Comment: Never mind, I'm dumb. `$div.htm();`. Thanks